# Including null values in SQL Sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to list the shipping city and state for the order with the longest shipping delay.

I can accomplish this like so:

```
SELECT shipcity, shipstate
FROM orders
WHERE shipdate - orderdate = (SELECT MAX(shipdate - orderdate) FROM orders);
```

But how can I also include orders which have not yet shipped so the shipdate val is NULL?

I have tried

```
SELECT shipcity, shipstate
FROM orders
WHERE (shipdate IS NULL) 
   OR (shipdate - orderdate = (SELECT MAX(shipdate - orderdate) FROM orders));
```

But this returns all the orders not just the order with the longest delay.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - [mcve]. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: What does it mean when shipdate is NULL?

Comment: It probably isnt shipped yet.

Comment: `SELECT shipcity, shipstate, (orders.shipdate - orders.orderdate) as delay_time
    FROM orders
    WHERE shipdate IS NULL
       OR delay_time = (SELECT MAX(shipdate - orderdate) FROM orders);`

Comment: I don't think your first query works correctly in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT shipcity, shipstate
FROM orders
WHERE (shipdate - orderdate = (SELECT MAX(shipdate - orderdate) FROM orders)) 
OR  (shipdate IS NULL and orderdate is NOT NULL )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
SELECT shipcity, shipstate
FROM orders
WHERE shipdate IS NOT NULL AND
      DATEDIFF(shipdate, orderdate) = (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(shipdate, orderdate)) FROM orders);
```

**DATEDIFF**
The DATEDIFF() function returns the number of days between two date values.

**SQL FIDDLE Sample**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6df39a/4